# transfer custom itinerary from Maps on PC to Android

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-navigation, data-transfer

I have a custom itinerary I prepared on maps.google.com on my PC (forcing some routing) and I would like to transfer it to my android smartphone, then use the navigation features of the Maps app.

The only thing I managed to do is to open this itinerary in a browser (on maps.google.com via the link I get on the PC) but not to transfer it to the Maps app. Is there a way to do this? Does the Maps app even supports custom routes?

Answer (score 0):

Install [Google Maps Engine](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.m4b).

> Google Maps Engine on Android enables you to view your custom maps
>   anywhere, anytime.

I'm not sure, but Navigation will probably not work as described here:

> For navigation, searching for local places, etc. please check out the
>   Google Maps for Mobile app.

Comment: I tried but I do not even know how to bring in my custom maps inside (it is bound to my account but does not see my maps, only a few public ones).